# Validation error when trying to log in to app using Amazon Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli, aws-amplify-sdk-js

After making updates to my aws app, I'm suddenly getting this error when trying to log in.

```
2 validation errors detected: Value '_______@gmail.com' at 'userName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\p{L}\p{M}\p{S}\p{N}\p{P}]+; Value '______@gmail.com' at 'userAlias' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\p{L}\p{M}\p{S}\p{N}\p{P}]+
```

This doesn't seem to occur on all accounts, only certain accounts in our pool. I can't find any information on this. Has anyone encountered this or has ideas on what might be causing it?

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HVrv.jpg)